# Bind multiple properties to multiple attributes of textbox in silverlight4

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a complex type as below

```
 public class EmployeessList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LatName { get; set; }

}
```

im binding list of above complextype to the datagrid so

```
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="150*" >
                                                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
<TextBox x:Name="{Binding Id}"  Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}"   />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
                                                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

As mentioned above I want to bind multiple properties to multiple attributes of textbox like

when I run this code it is giving error xaml parse exception as below.

```
---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The name already exists in the tree: . [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)

   at System.Windows.ResourceManagerWrapper.GetResourceForUri(Uri xamlUri, Type componentType)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)

   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(DependencyObject obj, String name)

   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.DataTemplate_LoadContent(DataTemplate template)

   at System.Windows.DataTemplate.LoadContent()

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn.GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, Object dataItem)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn.GenerateElementInternal(DataGridCell cell, Object dataItem)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PopulateCellContent(Boolean isCellEdited, DataGridColumn dataGridColumn, DataGridRow dataGridRow, DataGridCell dataGridCell)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.AddNewCellPrivate(DataGridRow row, DataGridColumn column)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CompleteCellsCollection(DataGridRow dataGridRow)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.GenerateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 slot, Object dataContext)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.GenerateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 slot)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.InsertDisplayedElement(Int32 slot, Boolean updateSlotInformation)

   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.GetExactSlot…
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: what you want to expected result? first of all x:Name="{Binding Id}" is not valid in binding

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part:

```
x:Name="{Binding Id}"
```

You cannot bind the x:Name property (sources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189028%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). Could you explain what do you want to achieve by binding that property? Maybe it can be done in other way.